# Verifying a win in a tic tac toe game using a 2D array and pictureboxes in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, comparison, tic-tac-toe

I am fairly new to coding and especially new to windows forms but I am trying to make a tic tac toe game. I have made the majority of it but cannot seem to get the comparison working. If player1's piece is in a spot then that spot will be set to true and false for player2 and null if it hasn't been used.This is what I have at the moment (I know it's not the neatest way of doing it) Please could someone tell me why it doesn't work properly:

```
    private void check()
    {
        if ((board[0, 0] != null) && (board[1, 0] != null) && (board[2, 0] != null) && (board[0, 0] == board[1, 0] && board[1, 0] == board[2, 0]))
        {
            winner = true;
            displaywinner();
        }
        if ((board[0, 1] != null) && (board[1, 1] != null) && (board[2, 1] != null) && (board[0, 1] == board[1, 1] && board[1, 1] == board[2, 1]))
        {
            winner = true;
            displaywinner();
        }
        if ((board[0, 2] != null) && (board[1, 2] != null) && (board[2, 2] != null) && (board[0, 2] == board[1, 2] && board[1, 2] == board[2, 2]))
        {
            winner = true;
            displaywinner();
        }
        if ((board[0, 0] != null) && (board[0, 1] != null) && (board[0, 2] != null) && (board[0, 0] == board[0, 1] && board[0, 1] == board[0, 2]))
        {
            winner = true;
            displaywinner();
        }
        if ((board[1, 0] != null) && (board[1, 1] != null) && (board[1, 2] != null) && (board[1, 0] == board [1, 2] && board[1, 2] == board [1, 2]))
        {
            winner = true;
            displaywinner();
        }
        if ((board[2, 0] != null) && (board[2, 1] != null) && (board[2, 2] != null) && (board[2, 0] == board[2, 1] && board[2, 1] == board[2, 2]))
        {
            winner = true;
            displaywinner();
        }
        if ((board[0, 0] != null) && (board[1, 1] != null) && (board[2, 2] != null) && (board[0, 0] == board[1, 1] && board[1, 1] == board[2, 2]))
        {
            winner = true;
            displaywinner();
        }
        if ((board[0, 2] != null) && (board[1, 1] != null) && (board[2, 0] != null) && ((board[0, 2] == board[1,1]) && (board[1, 1] == board[2, 0])))
        {
            winner = true;
            displaywinner();
        }
    }
    private void displaywinner()
    {
        if (winner == true)
        {
            if (turn == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(player1_name + " won");
            }
            else if (turn == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(player2_name + " won");
            }
            turn = !turn;
            newGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

Comment: When do you call your `check` method? It looks like it will only work if you call it after every move, while no one has won in the previous move. Do you change `turn` by any other means after every turn? Your pasted code only toggles `turn` when a winner has been found.

Comment: And a tip to make your code more readable: Create a method that checks a triplet of `bool?`s for your win condition so that you can call it with every row, column or diagonal. Something like `HasTripletWon(board[0,0], board[0,1], board[0,2])`.